# How can i change the url path when i receive the response of (xhr.response) to charge the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

```
newxhr.open("GET","/connected", true);
newxhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
newxhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')));
newxhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(newxhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && newxhr.status == 200){
           //The problem is here 
           window.location.href="/home";

       }
}
```

The actual location is '*/connexion*' the post worked and i get the token from the server so i did the GET to '*/home*' but it still in the same page  :notice '/home is a protected route' can't get it without a token,

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do and what is the problem exactly, do you have any error message?

Comment: `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found` i have this like error but it's normal because the window.location.href="/home" will do a get request but without the token in the header